# Do I have to keep the fragment id's inside navigation graph as same as menu item id?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-navigation-graph

I am trying to understand the code structure of default Navigation drawer created in android studio 3.6.3. In Navigation drawer when menu item is clicked it shows it corresponding fragment layout. I am trying to understand the mechanism. I have found that the navigation graph fragments id name and menu item id name are both same. I have first changed the menu item id name and called inside main activity using (R.id.menu_id). And when I launch the application the navigation menu were not functioning. Then I renamed the menu id name to as it was and changed the fragment's id name. But unfortunately after launching the app the menus didn't functioned. When I kept the both name same the menu works.

Inside (resource/navigation/mobile_navigation.xml).
[image: mobile_navigation.xml]

Inside (resource/menu/activity_main_drawer.xml)
[image: activity_main_drawer.xml]

Inside (java/MainActivity.java)
[image: MainActivity.java]

Need someone guide on am I understanding wrong or not.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: any answer you got?